# Laravel, Call to undefined function Database\Seeders\factory()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I get the title error when I run command:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

My screenshot:
[image]

I have no idea where this problem comes from. I was searching for code examples and solution but I haven't found anything :(

ArticlesTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
// use Laracasts\TestDummy\Factory as TestDummy;

class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Models\Article::class, 30)->create();
    }
}
```

ArticleFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ModelFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = App\Models\Article::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $faker->text(50),
            'body' => $faker->text(200)
        ];
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(ArticlesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: you don't use the `factory` helper function anymore it would seem ... you should check the documentation on how to call these factories  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#using-factories

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In laravel 8 the default route namespace was removed.

Try to change:

**ArticlesTableSeeder.php:**

```
 factory(App\Models\Article::class, 30)->create();
```

to:

```
\App\Models\Article::factory()->count(30)->create();
```

**ArticleFactory.php:**

```
protected $model = App\Models\Article::class;
```

to:

```
protected $model = \App\Models\Article::class;
```

and you will probably have to change:

```
 'title' => $faker->text(50),
            'body' => $faker->text(200)
```

to:

```
 'title' => $this->faker->text(50),
        'body' => $this->faker->text(200)
```

Comment: You should have mentioned that the helper method `factory()` was removed in Laravel 8

Answer (score 17):

All suggestions that were mentioned here are correct.
Sometimes running `composer require laravel/legacy-factories` might fix your problem if you're using Laravel 8.
Also, in case you get an error that says `Class 'Database\Factories\ArticleFactory' not found`
then make sure you have `class ArticleFactory extends Factory` and not ModalFactory.
And make sure you're using HasFactory in the Article Model like here.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

For more info: [Laravel 8 Modal Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#model-factories)

Answer (score 11):

Try to change

```
factory(App\Models\Article::class, 30)->create();
```

to

```
App\Models\Article::factory()->count(30)->create();
```

Answer (score 8):

ArticlesTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ArticlesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Article::factory()->times(30)->create();
    }
}
```

ArticleFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ArticleFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Article::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->text(50),
            'body'  => $this->faker->text(200)
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using version 8 of laravel, look at the upgrade guide.
"Laravel's model factories feature has been totally rewritten to support classes and is not compatible with Laravel 7.x style factories. However, to ease the upgrade process, a new laravel/legacy-factories package has been created to continue using your existing factories with Laravel 8.x. You may install this package via Composer:

composer require laravel/legacy-factories"

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#seeder-factory-namespaces

Answer (score 2):

change

‍`factory(App\Models\Article::class, 30)->create(); ‍`

to

`\App\Models\Article::factory(30)->create();`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same issue when I realized my model was not using the HasFactory trait.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'categories';
   
}
```

So make sure this trait is being used by your model.

Comment: This was exactly my problem, thank you! It isn't as clear as it could be in the docs (for me, at least) because I normally look at the code snippets to see what I have to include, whereas in this case it was mentioned in the body of the docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-and-model-discovery-conventions

Answer (score -1):

If you are using version 8 of laravel you can directory use:

use App\Models\Article;
Article::factory()->count(30)->create();

Answer (score -1):

1. composer require laravel/legacy-factories
2. php artisan db:seed

Answer (score -1):

Use

$this->faker->name()  instead of

fake()->name() method.