# Old vs new? Or what is the difference factory method definition() and $factory->define()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Following [Your First Laravel application](https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application) tutorial on laravel-news.com I came to a point where I need to edit `LinkFactory.php` created by `$ php artisan make:model --factory Link`.

The default code created by `make` is the following:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Link;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class LinkFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Link::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

And the tutorial suggest to replace that code with the following:

```php
<?php
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
use App\Link;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
$factory->define(Link::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => substr($faker->sentence(2), 0, -1),
        'url' => $faker->url,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
    ];
});
```

I understand some namespacing differences ie. `App\Link -> App\Models\Link` and `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory -> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory` and the need to add `Faker\Generator as Faker`, but I'm not sure what to do with the rest.

I'm thinking something like the following:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Link;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

class LinkFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Link::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $faker = new Faker;
        
        return [
            'title' => substr($faker->sentence(2), 0, -1),
            'url' => $faker->url,
            'description' => $faker->paragraph,
        ];
    }
}
```

First, I need to know if this is correct, and how it is not.

Second, I don't know if I need to use the `$model` property anywhere here.

And third, how does that affect any further usage elsewhere in code?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I found this answer about [Undefined `factory()` helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816395/laravel-call-to-undefined-function-database-seeders-factory), I think my question may be marked as [duplicate].

This is working now.

LinkFactory.php

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Link;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class LinkFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Link::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {        
        return [
            'title' => substr($this->faker->sentence(2), 0, -1),
            'url' => $this->faker->url,
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraph,
        ];
    }
}
```

LinksTableSeeder.php

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Link;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class LinksTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Link::factory()->count(30)->create();
    }
}
```

I also had to change DatabaseSeeder.php to

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(LinksTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

and then ran

```sh
$ php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

and the database was populated.