# cannot use php artisan migrate --seed at laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can't user command 'php artisan migrate --seed'

This is my problem

```
Call to undefined function factory()
 at C:\Users\Potato\Documents\GitHub\rent-cars\database\seeds\UserSeeder.php:15
     11▕      * @return void
     12▕      */
     13▕     public function run()
     14▕     {
  ➜  15▕         factory(User::class, 1)->create();
     16▕
     17▕         $this->command->info('User added succesfully');
     18▕     }
     19▕ }

  1   C:\Users\Potato\Documents\GitHub\rent-cars\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      UserSeeder::run()

  2   C:\Users\Potato\Documents\GitHub\rent-cars\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php:41
      Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
```

And this my UserSeeder.php

create();

        $this->command->info('User added succesfully');
    }
}



I tried to fix this, please help me, and i'm sorry about my bad english

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel, Call to undefined function Database\Seeders\factory()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816395/laravel-call-to-undefined-function-database-seeders-factory)

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload` first before seeding.

Comment: I am 99.9% sure you are using Laravel 8+, where `factory()` helper is not used anymore but `Model::factory()`. As always, read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories)...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using,

```
factory(User::class, 1)->create();
```

Use this,

```
User::factory(1)->create();
```

or

```
User::factory()->count(1)->create();
```